# Failed to create route route1

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

i have a trouble solving this exception and i don't know where i'm doing wrong. 
here's the Exception.

```
org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootInitializationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> Filter[bean[ref:filter method:accept] -> []] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[file:D:/copyy/?noop=true]] -> [Filter[be... because of Definition has no children on Filter[bean[ref:filter method:accept] -> []]

Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> Aggregate[true -> []] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[file:D:/xml/?noop=true]] -> [Aggregate[t... because of Definition has no children on Aggregate[true -> []]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Definition has no children on Aggregate[true -> []]
```

and here's my router :

```
<bean id="AggregatorDemo" class="com.javainuse.AggregatorDemo"/> 
<route>
    <from uri="file:D:/xml/?noop=true" />
        <aggregate strategyRef="AggregatorDemo">
        <correlationExpression>
        <constant>true</constant>
        </correlationExpression>
        </aggregate>
        <log message=".....${body}...."></log>
        <to uri="file:D:/Xmlcopy" />
</route>
```

and here's the aggregator class i'm using.

```
public class AggregatorDemo implements AggregationStrategy{

 public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {

        if (oldExchange == null) {

            return newExchange;
        }

        String orders = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String newLine = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);


        orders = orders+ newLine;

        oldExchange.getIn().setBody(orders);


        return oldExchange;
 }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move these inside the `<aggregate>`

```
<log message=".....${body}...."></log>
<to uri="file:D:/Xmlcopy" />
```

So the aggregate has children, eg

```
 <aggregate strategyRef="AggregatorDemo">
   <correlationExpression>
     <constant>true</constant>
   </correlationExpression>
   <log message=".....${body}...."></log>
   <to uri="file:D:/Xmlcopy" />
 </aggregate>
```