# Apache-camel corda component connection error: Failed to create route route1

Tags: apache-camel, corda

I am trying the connect to Corda using that component and sending data to Apache ActiveMQ again using Apache Camel's Corda component.

Corda is running properly. Particularly, cardapp-example is running, and Notary- PartyA - PartyB and PartyC are alive. I can query using their terminal.
ActiveMQ is working properly, I test it with another input source.
I've also tried to connect difeerent localhost ports of all four nodes, and also the example one showed in the Camel's corda component webpage.

```
public class CordaConnector {
    public void ConnectToCorda() throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        context.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("corda://localhost:10004?username=user1&password=test&operation=VAULT_TRACK&contractStateClass=#contractStateClass").
            }
        });

        while(true) {
            context.start();
        }
    }
}
```

I got the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[From[corda://localhost:10004?username=user1&pa... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: corda://localhost:10004?contractStateClass=%23contractStateClass&operation=VAULT_TRACK&password=test&username=user1 due to: Error binding property (contractStateClass=#contractStateClass) with name: contractStateClass on bean: org.apache.camel.component.corda.CordaConfiguration@1de76cc7 with value: #contractStateClass
...
```

So when tested seperately, corda works properly, ActiveMQ works properly (with different output), and I ave tried different ports to query information. I have alos tried different commands to query, such as:

```
from("corda://localhost:10000?username=user1&password=test&operation=NETWORK_MAP_FEED").
to("activemq:queue:try");
```

I've checked this question [Failed to create route route1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47428260/failed-to-create-route-route1), but was no help.
I would appreciate any help on what might be the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your route `from` uri, you are setting the `contractStateClass` property using value `#contractStateClass` : this references a bean named `contractStateClass` in the Camel registry. But since you did not bind any bean with this name in the context registry, Camel fail to resolve this value: `Error binding property (contractStateClass=#contractStateClass) with name: contractStateClass on bean: org.apache.camel.component.corda.CordaConfiguration@1de76cc7 with value: #contractStateClass`

You simply need to configure a bean of type `Class` and provide it to the camel registry. Something like that should work ( camel version 2.24.x )

```
import net.corda.core.contracts.OwnableState;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry;

public class CordaConnector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
            registry.put("contractStateClass", OwnableState.class);
            CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
            camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() {
                    from("corda://localhost:10004?username=user1&password=test&operation=VAULT_TRACK&contractStateClass=#contractStateClass")
                            .log("got message");
                }
            });
            camelContext.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT**  for Camel v3.x :

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.support.SimpleRegistry;

public class CordaConnector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
            registry.bind("contractStateClass", MyContractClass.class);
            CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
            camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() {
                    from("corda://localhost:10004?username=user1&password=test&operation=VAULT_TRACK&contractStateClass=#contractStateClass")
                            .log("got message");
                }
            });
            camelContext.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thansk for the reply, but it didn't solve the problem. First, I encountered the compile error, that notifies registry.Put() requires HashMap<java.lang.Class<?>, Object> as second argument. What kind of object should I use here?

Comment: Hi. maybe you did not import the correct class?   `SimpleRegistry` from camel-support library extends `LinkedHashMap` , so `put(String, Object)` is available, see https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-support/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/support/SimpleRegistry.java .  Please note that this was a simple example, if your project uses Spring you might simply register  the `contractStateClass` as a Bean on the Spring application context. I have updated my answer with the used imports.

Comment: Thanks again. You are right, error is somehow related to the imported class... Because, in my imports it can not resolve:
import org.apache.camel. _impl_ .SimpleRegistry , but it only imports:
import org.apache.camel. _support_. SimpleRegistry

I am using maven, and the latest version there, which is **3.0.0-RC1**. Can you please let me know what maven repo, version are you using? Or are you using another source?

Comment: sorry my mistake: `SimpleRegistry` is provided by `camel-core` not `camel-support`, but I'm using Camel version 2.24.x ( see https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.24.x/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/SimpleRegistry.java , previous link was wrong). It seems that refactoring was made in Camel 3.x and this class is no longer available in camel-core

Comment: I updated my answer with a working example based on Camel v3.x. you now need to use `SimpleRegistry.bind()` method;   `SimpleRegistry` has been moved to `camel-support` module. Note that you need to provide a real available class for `contractStateClass`, in my example I used fake class.

Comment: As I understand I need to add my code to Cordapp-Example directory(that is the directory contains the running Corda 's code), since I need to reference the class from this code. I am stuck with this part, and trying to figure out where should I add this new module in the Cordapp-Example project directory. Do you have any idea, is this the only/true way of doing and how it should be done? Thanks again.

Comment: You just need to update your existing code, in order to declare the `contractStateClass` on the Camel registry, or remove the `contractStateClass` from the endpoint URI.

Comment: Probably I missing something but, as a separate project containing the above code of corda camel connection, it doesn't know what is the class named _MyContractClass?, as it is defined in another project directory, that runs the corda app, _Cordapp-Example_. So this class information somehow needs to be accesible by the camel-corda connection project, am I wrong? 

Besides, _VAULT_TRACK_ requires contractStateClass to be given as parameter. Since even when run in the one of the running corda node's terminal directly. So it is not possible to send to command without it, right?

Comment: Hi. `MyContractClass` does not exist it's a fake class I used for the example. you must choose your own implementation of contract class and use it in your project. In the `camel-corda` test sources they use `OwnableState` ( see https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-corda/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/corda/CordaConsumerTestSupport.java ) .  I have answered your initial issue related to missing declared `contractStateClass` bean instance on the Camel registry;  now if you have other issues you should open new question. br

Comment: Yes, I know that and it was not actually my question, but the link you provide is helpful anyways. Thanks for the answer, with regards.